# Rewriting query URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Suppose I have URLs with query string parameters like these:

```
index.php?lag=en&name=About Us&itemid=60
index.php?host=consumer&lag=en&name=About Us&itemid=64
```

Using mod_rewrite, how can I redirect them like these?

```
en_About Us_60.php
consumer/en_About Us_64.php
```

In the Above urls values are dynamic.

Comment: I'm quite sure you mean the contrary, you want url to be shown in the en_About Us_60.php for the user and redirected to index.php?lag=en&name=About Us&itemid=60 fot the application, isn't it? And are you sure you want a redirect or just a transparent rewrite?

Comment: Yep, I want to be redirect index.php?lag=en&name=About Us&itemid=60
index.php?host=consumer&lag=en&name=About Us&itemid=64 these two dynamic url to static url like en_About Us_60.php
consumer/en_About Us_64.php
this.Please help me

Comment: you say yes and then you say the contrary of my sentence... write in your question the url for the user and the url for your app. Do you have a en_About Us_64.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} host=(.*)&lag=(.*)&name=(.*)&itemid=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /%1/%2_%3_%4 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lag=(.*)&name=(.*)&itemid=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /%1_%2_%3 [QSA]
```

Remember, to check all the statements, which are possible ;)